# Using += in a while loop but need to exclude highest number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was tasked with creating a program that takes all the inputted numbers and adds them together except the highest integer out of that list. I am suppose to use while and if then logic but I cannot figure out how to exclude the highest number. I also had to make the program break when the string "end" was put into the console. So far I have,

```
total = 0
while 1 >= 1 :
    value = input("Enter the next number: ")
    if value != "end":
        num = float(value)
        total += num
    if value == 'end':
        print("The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: ",total)
        return total
        break
```

I just have no idea how to make it disregard the highest inputted number. Thanks in advance! I am using python 3 fyi.

Comment: Why don't you add them all up and keep track of the max and at the end subtract the max from net total? Did I miss something in your question?

Comment: I can't add them all up manually because I have to keep it in an infinite loop until the user types "end".
edit: Just thought about your answer more. That would work, but I don't know how to tell the program to keep track of the highest number. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No I mean just add one line to keep track of the max, as you take inputs and at the end return `total-max`

Comment: Have added a check for that too in the answer. It might not work for max = some False-y values, but you can figure that out right? :)

Comment: An infinite loop in Python is `while True:`. Also, your two if-clauses would be clearer if you used `else`. That said, none of your homework description suggests that you have to sum up the numbers inside of the loop, you can also store them in a list, remove the maximum and sum them up then. BTW: There's even a `sum()` function in Python for that!

Comment: If this is inside a function, you don't need `break` after `return`. If this is outside a function, you need to remove `return` or get a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
total = 0
maxValue = None
while True:
    value = input("Enter the next number: ")
    if value != "end":
        num = float(value)
        maxValue = num if maxValue and num > maxValue else num
        total += num
    else:
        print("The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: ",total-maxValue )
        # return outside a function is SyntaxError
        break
```

Comment: You should also print the correct value: `print("The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: ",total - max)`

Comment: I didn't see there was another place for that. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for that! I was stuck on the logic and did not really know about the max function. I'm really new to python so it's taking a while for me to get use to the logic.

Comment: @George There's no `max` function being used here.

Comment: `return` outside a function is `SyntaxError`

Comment: @George Like Barmar points, `while True` will work just as fine

Comment: @Obsidian What font is everyone using that makes it hard to tell the difference between `r` and `n`?

Comment: @George `max` is just an ordinary variable holding a number. If it were a function, you would call it like `max(a, b)`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh ok thank you for the info. I edited the code and it worked.

Comment: I think it would be better to spell the infinite loop `while True:`, and use if/else.

Comment: @Obsidian I decided to use `if maxValue < num: maxValue = num` The code earlier for some reason wouldn't register the highest number if it wasn't put last. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @George The first if case is necessary in my case, because I initialized `maxValue = None` so when the first number is entered, `if maxValue` evaluates to `False` and the else `num` is assigned. Thereafter `if maxValue` will always be `True` and the second condition `maxValue<num` gets checked.

Comment: If it worked without the first condition, can you please share how you made do without the first condition?

Comment: @Obsidian I used `maxValue=0` to start my equation instead. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go in regards to keeping it close to your original. Using lists is great in python for this sort of thing.

```
list = []

while True:
    num = input("Please enter value")
    if num == "end":
        list.remove(max(list))
        return sum(list)
    else:
        list.append(int(num))
```

if you input 1,2 and 3 this would output 3 - it adds the 1 and 2 and discards the original 3.

You've said it's an assignment so if lists aren't allowed then you could use

```
max = 0
total = 0
while True:
    num = input("Please enter value")
    if str(num) == "end":
        return total - max
    if max < int(num):
        max = int(num)
    total += int(num)
```

Comment: Hmm.  It seems much cleaner to me to accumulate a total and a max, and subtract the max.  Also, can we teach the OP (who is obviously a beginner) that an infinite loop in python is spelt `while True:` please.

Comment: Agreed on the True, however i've always found the ease of manipulating lists one of the best parts of python, so it may be good for OP to see. But i will updated to have a non list version as well as it may be against OP's assignment.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to achieve the result you want is to use python's builtin max function (that is if you don't care about performance, because this way you are actually iterating over the list 2 times instead of one).

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum(a) - max(a)
```

This not exactly the same as you want it to do, but the result is going to be the same (Since instead of not adding the largest item you can just subtract it in the end).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
total = 0
highest = None
while True:
    value = input("Enter the next number: ")
    if value != 'end':
        num = float(value)
        if highest is None or num > highest:
            highest = num
        total += num
    else:
        break
print("The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: ",total-highest )
print(total-highest)
```